# What does the + mean?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

What do the two `+` signs mean between `xmin` and `ymin` in my code?

Why are there two "+"?

```
grenzen = "(" + xmin + ", " + ymin + ") - " + "(" + xmax + ", " + ymax + ").";
```

Comment: List of operators in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Comment: [Google: C# + operator](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+%2B+operator&oq=c%23+%2B+operator&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j60j61j62l2.2537j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [this is the first result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)

Comment: Easier-to-read version: `grenzen = string.Format("({0}, {1}) - ({2}, {3}).", xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)`.

Comment: I don't quiet understand what is the downvote for. Certainly, it is not a good question, but it is a proper question. It contains piece of code, and contains what he want to know. Since he is new to programming and not an English native speaker, maybe he is not good at Google (search is a skill too). Let say if he search "C# +", the 20 first results are not related to his question.

Comment: @invisal The downvotes are for a lack of research effort. It's true that the query "C# +" doesn't return anything useful, but "C# + operator" does, and "operator" is a valid German word (which is taught during maths classes at the tender age of ~12) and also carries the same meaning as its English pendant. Besides, I have yet to encounter a single programming tutorial that mentions operators without explicitly referring to them as "operator", so I fail to see the research effort here, thus the -1 on my part.

Answer (score 12):

It [concatenates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx) two strings into one. From the documentation:

> Concatenation is the process of appending one string to the end of
>   another string. When you concatenate string literals or string
>   constants by using the + operator, the compiler creates a single
>   string. No run time concatenation occurs. However, string variables
>   can be concatenated only at run time. In this case, you should
>   understand the performance implications of the various approaches.

In your case, it would be more efficient to use a `StringBuilder`<sup>[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)</sup>, `string.Format`<sup>[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)</sup>, or `string.Concat`<sup>[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx)</sup>, because strings are immutable and thus, each concatenation operator produces a whole new string object.

Comment: +1 for the link to the doc!

Comment: Would be that right too?

Comment: And this is how rep is farmed on SO.

Comment: grenzen = ("xmin "+ " ymin");

Comment: @barbarian1 No, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6):

This is string concatenation. You could also do something like this:

```
string.Format("({0}, {1}) - ({2}, {3}).", xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
```

and get the same result -but it's more efficient **and** more readable. Consider this, when you do this operation:

```
"(" + xmin;
```

which is a much smaller operation than what you have above, internally .NET has to allocate an array that is 1 character long first, then it's going to evaluate the string length of `xmin` and then build a new array that's the length of those two together, copy the first array into it, and stuff the result of `xmin` on the end.

However, with `string.Format` it's able to calculate the size of the array up front and thus only requires one allocation trip, making it **much** more efficient.

Another way, that's at least more efficient than string concatenation, would be to leverage a `StringBuilder` because it's mutable:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("(");
sb.Append(xmin);
...
```

The reason this is more efficient than string concatenation is because when you add a string to the `StringBuilder` it expands its capacity past that what you added. As an example, if I added one character, it may expand its capacity to twenty. **NOTE:** that's not the actual algorithm, I'm just trying to give you the idea.

Comment: Good answer, but technically, don't forget to count the `\0` null-terminator.

Comment: @YoryeNathan, ah yes. Thanks! I did in fact forget about that because I just don't do it by hand that often. :D

Comment: @YoryeNathan So, if I were to ever use the `StringBuilder` class, I'd have to append the `\0` null-terminator by hand? Doesn't it happen automatically when I call `StringBuilder.ToString()`?

Comment: @Nolonar, no you wouldn't have to append it at all, it's just implied. He was more speaking to my math when it comes to array allocation.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Ah, I see. I was worried for a while, since I didn't want my client to come knocking on my door, just because my app crashed due to a missing null-terminator xD

Comment: You are forgetting the overhead of parsing the format string and the allocation of the StringBuilder Object (Which string.format uses under the covers anyway to build the final string). String.Concat(...) (which is what string concatenation gets converted to) actually is far more efficient with four or less strings as that calls unsafe code and that (as far as I can tell) does what you think string.format does.  Granted 5+ strings gets said strings converted into a `string[]`, and I rember someone saying that about 10 strings is the cutoff point for String.Concat vs StringBuilder.

Comment: `String.Join` and `StringBuilder` are most efficient ways of concatenating strings, each with it's own specialized usages. However, tests show that a simple `+` concatenation is after all faster for very small amounts of concatenations (if I remember correctly, it is best for 7 concatenations and below, but I might be mistaken. Test it!)

Answer (score 5):

'+' is used for string concatination in c#

Eg.

```
string x = "1";
string y = "2";
string z = "3";
string all = x + y + z;
```

gives `all="123"`

Use of '+' can be done also in following way:

```
x += y;
```

Comment: But you have only one +. In my codes are two between each variable.   grenzen = "(" + xmin + ", " + ymin + ") - " + "(" + xmax + ", " + ymax + ").";

Comment: grenzen is collectively going to be a string, so to concate or enclose value of xmin between two '(' ')' + is used.

Comment: @barbarian1 `(` + x + `, ` + y + `)` => `(1, 2)`. What part of it do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

Here `+` sign is using for string concatenation.

```
string message="This "+ "is" +" my "+" book";
```

output : This is my book

Answer (score 1):

it is a concatenation operator to join two strings

Answer (score 0):

Here it is concatenating strings.

In C# `+` works two ways

It adds if both operands are numbers like `2 + 3` whose result is `5` and

It concatenates if one or both operand is/are string like `'First' + 'Name'` whose result is `"FirstName"`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to look at code more careful. The type of the variables and so the objects says which operations are allowed. In thinking of that, the variables have to have string operators, so it is a good guess that it are string.

(also from Germany)